# Several usage of sql with alias

Tags: sql, sql-server, with-statement, with-clause

I want to use several time alias of with clause on SQL server.

Example:

```
WITH name1 AS (
     SELECT ...
)

SELECT * from name1
SELECT * from name1 ORDER BY name
```

Is it possible?
I'm getting "Invalid object name " error

Comment: Create a view instead. It can be used in different queries.

Comment: The CTE is 
subsequent statement  it can be a single SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE, or a compound (with UNION, INTERSECT etc)

Comment: You can only do the first SELECT from the CTE name1. The second SELECT is giving you the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to use is a `CTE`, which is available for use only in the immediately following DML

```
WITH name1 AS (
     SELECT ...
)

SELECT * from name1
```

That part will work fine. The next `select` statement will not have access to the `CTE`. You can try using a `table variable` instead

Answer (score 0):

Common Table Expressions as below syntax :

```
WITH name1 AS 
(
  SELECT ...
)

SELECT * from name1
```

You can use only one SELECT statement for CTE table .If you want to use CTE 
table more than once,Just you move to that CTE table to temp table and use that table at all place.